# PHP - Nested foreach() in a module and in a view

Tags: php, html, foreach

I am new to arrays I used string variables instead of arrays, but now decided to learn the language as a professional, I am currently getting categories by calling a method inside a class, and trying to get subcategories of each and every fetched category

in the module (pure logic no HTML)the code is like this:

```
// FOR THE MENU, GET ALL CATEGORIES
$cats = $cat->getCategories();
// FOR THE MENU, GET ALL SUBCATEGORIES IN A GIVEN CATEGORY
foreach($cats as $cat){
 $sub_cats = $sub_cat->getSubCategoriesByCategoryId($cat['id']);
}
```

NOTE: the code is fetching all the data correctly

In the view (PHP results injected into HTML)

```
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat){ ?>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $cat['name']; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php foreach ($cat['id'] as $sub_cat){ ?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $sub_cat['name']; ?></a></li>
      <?php } ?>
     </ul>
  </li>
<?php } ?>
```

the view code is not working, the dropdown shows the following error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/b/header.php on line 52

Comment: what does var_dump($cats) get you?

Comment: Make sure `$sub_cat` array have values?

Comment: echoing the following $cat['name'] is giving me the right values, but echoing $sub_cat['name'] is returning the error mentioned above, and ues the database tables contain test values

Comment: I think the problem could be in `foreach ($cat['id'] as $sub_cat)`... isn't `$cat["id"]` a single value? are you trying to do a `foreach` in a single value?

Comment: maybe we can try this function?    foreach($cats as $cat => $sub_cat){ I lack the experience in foreach()

Comment: I am trying to get main categories and then the sub categories of each fetched category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, you must save subcats for every cat, something like this

```
// FOR THE MENU, GET ALL CATEGORIES
$cats = $cat->getCategories();
// FOR THE MENU, GET ALL SUBCATEGORIES IN A GIVEN CATEGORY
$sub_cats = array();
foreach($cats as $cat){
   $sub_cats[$cat['id']] = $sub_cat->getSubCategoriesByCategoryId($cat['id']);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<?php foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
  <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $cat['name']; ?> <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <?php foreach ($sub_cats[$cat["id"]] as $sub_cat):?>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $sub_cat['name']; ?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I guess that is it I will try it and let you know

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Then, mark this as selected answer. ;)